# Cannot insert Array in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a *CSV* file with the following data:

```
  eno |           phonelist           |  shots

  "1" | "['1112223333','6195551234']" | "[[11,12]]"
```

The DDL statement I have used to create table in snowflake is  as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ArrayTable (eno INTEGER, phonelist array,shots array);
```

I need to insert the data from the *CSV* into the Snowflake table and the method I have used is:

```
create or replace stage ArrayTable_stage file_format = (TYPE=CSV)

put file://ArrayTable @ArrayTable_stage auto_compress=true

copy into ArrayTable from @ArrayTable_stage/ArrayTable.gz 
    file_format = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='|' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='\"\')
```

But when I try to run the code, I get the error:

> Copy to table failed: 100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON:
> ('1112223333','6195551234')

How to resolve this?

Comment: what output do you get when you run `SELECT column2, TRY_PARSE_JSON(column2) as j from @ArrayTable_stage/ArrayTable.gz 
    file_format = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='|' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='\"\')
WHERE j is null` it will show you all that inputs in the file that are not converting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='\"\'` base on the row you have that should just be `'\"'`

```
select parse_json('[\'1112223333\',\'6195551234\']');
```

works (the back slashes are to get around the sql parser)

but your output has parens `(`, `)` which is different.

```
SELECT column2, TRY_PARSE_JSON(column2) as j 
FROM @ArrayTable_stage/ArrayTable.gz
      file_format = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='|' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='\"\') 
WHERE j is null;
```

will show which values are failing to parse..

failing that you might want to use `to_array` to parse column2 and thus insert into you table the SELECTED/transformed data, that is failing to auto transform

Comment: Hi, the requirement is to modify the copy command to accept arrays, is there any parameter that can help me do it?

Comment: Yes, that is the point here. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#syntax the `/* Data load with transformation */` section shows you can put a select in the middle to transform your data, thus if you can workout how to read the data, you can poke it into a table in one command.

Comment: I'm using 'select $1, array_construct($2),array_construct($3) from @ArrayTable_stage/ArrayTable-1-1.csv.gz)'. Is there any alternate method to insert without calling array_construct for every column?

Comment: if that works I wouldn't be too worried, that transform cost is rather lower, and the IO from the bucket is normally the linear (to warehouse size) blocker. But try create the table where it's three text blocks and just load straight into that. I would propose the total processing time will be the same.

Comment: I will be inserting multiple tables, so selecting individual columns manually each time doesn't seem like a feasible idea.

Comment: one part of the experiment is to just find, "what ways are needed to be able to get this data to load" presently the solution is not "very scalable" you can ether just push everything to strings and then do a second stage transform. (twice+ the effort). Or find a magic combination of command to load your data as it is currently formatted, OR change how it's formatted.